# NSFetchResultsController sorting is not working when inserting new entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an CoreData entity called "MyPhoto" with the attributes :- photoData, timeStamp, folderName. Setting the today Date with Time to timeStamp property when saving photoData to core data. I want sections with folderName and inside the section I want to sort the photos with timeStamp. I am using and NSFetchResultsController to fetch the data & UICollectionView to display it.

Problem is: When I try to insert the new photo, it is not inserting in the correct sorting order but when I relaunch the app, it will show the all the photos in a correct sorting order.

here is the code I am using:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyPhoto" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Sort using the timeStamp property.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"folderName" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor1]];

    // Use the folderName property to group into sections.
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"folderName" cacheName:@"Root"];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

I hope I have explained my problem clearly. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are setting the delegate. Have you actually implemented any of the delegate methods?

For starters, you could just call `reloadData` in `controllerDidChangeContent:`